# How to select all entries on a Multi-select box

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'd like to know how to select all values inside a Multi-select box.

I've tried:

command: addSelection // target: id=COMP // value: *

No success, it just selects the first option. This Multi-select box has different values every time we log on the system, that's why I can't insert several addSelection commands with all values, because I don't know which values will appear there on the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it doable using javascript from Selenium IDE. Try this, using `id=COMP` for your `<select>` element:

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>runScript</td>
>   <td>var sel=document.getElementById('COMP'); for(var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel.options[i].selected=true; }</td>
>   <td></td>
> </tr>
> ```

(On a side note, I expected it to be doable by sending characters Shift+Ctrl+End to the element, but no matter what I tried I couldn't get Selenium IDE to send keys to a `<select>` element. Could do it fine with WebDriver.)